# Load video embedded content with xna

Tags: c#, video, xna, stream, media

I have a problem with XNA, i have video as embedded content (byte[] or stream) and i need to play this video. I can't find any converter to Video. Please help. I need PC support only. I don't know how to do this, maybe you know library which can make it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `VideoPlayer` class, and the video files must be in .wmv format.
Something like [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/how-to-use-video-in-xna/).

```
Video myVideoFile;
VideoPlayer videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();
```

Load content:

```
myVideoFile = Content.Load<Video>("Videos/video_name");
```

Update:

```
videoPlayer.Play(myVideoFile);
```

Draw:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(videoPlayer.GetTexture(), new Rectangle(0, 0, myVideoFile.Width, myVideoFile.Height),Color.CornflowerBlue);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: I tried this but "video_name.wmv" must be in contentProject. I need video as Embedded Content.